# Как на C++ преобразовать int в char?

Tags: c++, char, int

Мне нужно создать несколько тысяч файлов.txt и потом прочитать данные из них. Каждый файл должен быть пронумерован. Ещё желательно поделить их на категории, например: A126.txt B1235.txt или C684.txt. Экспериментировал я с таким кодом и у меня почему-то съедаются буквы

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int j = 0;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        char ch = char(i);
        //char ch = (char)i;
        //char ch = static_cast<char>(i);

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(ch + ".txt");
        if (!fout.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Ошибка записи в файл конфигурации!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            fout << i << endl;
        }
        fout.close();

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open(ch + ".txt");
        if (!fin.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Ошибка чтения файла конфигурации!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
                fin >> j;
        }
        fin.close();

        cout << ch + ".txt" << j << endl;
        cout << "j: " << j << endl;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Оставил комментарии с некоторыми экспериментами.

Comment: Вы путаете строки (текст) и `char`.

Comment: Пишите программы проще. `#define FIRST_CHAR "123456789ABCDEFGH" ... int main () { char filename[] = "x.txt"; for (int i = 0; FIRST_CHAR[i]; i++) {filename[0] = FIRST_CHAR[i]; ....`

Answer (score 2):

Удобную работу для создания строки есть в классе `stringstream`.  Вы можете писать/читать в этот поток что-нибудь и потом вывести результат строкой.

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char const* h[]={"ab","cd","ef","gh"};
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
        for(int j=10;j<14;++j){
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss<<h[i]<<j<<".txt";
            std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

```
ab10.txt
ab11.txt
ab12.txt
ab13.txt
cd10.txt
cd11.txt
cd12.txt
cd13.txt
ef10.txt
ef11.txt
ef12.txt
ef13.txt
gh10.txt
gh11.txt
gh12.txt
gh13.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас получается какие-то непечатные символы с кодами 1, 2, 3 и так далее. А потомы складывать символ с указателем строки - совсем не то, что нужно.

Можно попробовать сделать так

```
    string filename(1,'A');
    filename[0] += i;
    filename += ".txt";
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(filename.c_str());
```

и вы получите файлы `B.txt`, `C.txt` и дальше.

Comment: я написал так: ``` string filename(1, '0'); ``` и у меня действительно создаются файлы от 1 до 9, однако дальше идёт остальная таблица ASCII. Ну и из-за ограничения windows в названии файлов (что бы отсутствовали символы !  и другие) некоторые файлы не создаются и не читаются.

Comment: Вы определитесь точно, что вы хотите. У вас в коде создание 5 файлов. Они создаются. Опишите, как именно вы хотите создавать ваши тысячи файлов. В цикле? А как делить на категории? 25436-й файл к какой категории относится? В двух чиклах? Или как?

Comment: категория - это буква (либо несколько символов) в начале имени файла, после идут цифры и затем его расширение. мне нужно использовать сначала рандом с категорией, а потом из категории выбрать рандомное число. Таким образом будет получен доступ к файлу. Мне уже помогла нейросеть, у неё получилось так и это прекрасно работает:

        `std::string filename = "file" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";

        std::ofstream new_file;

        ofstream fout;

        fout.open(filename);`

Comment: И где здесь категории? Вы бы так и спросили, не растекаясь мыслью по древу - как получить имя файла, состоящее из числа. Но вы начали рассказывать о каких-то категориях...

Answer (score 0):

С кодом помогла нейросеть, делает именно то, что нужно:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        string filename = "file" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
        ofstream new_file;
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(filename);
            fout << i << endl;
        fout.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"file" меняется на нужную категорию.

Comment: Здесь нет никаких категорий. Впрочем, успехов в замене интеллекта на искусственный :) Кстати, показательно, что только ИИ сумел понять плохо заданный вопрос...